# Programmatically distinguishing multi-stores in magento?

Tags: sql, magento

How do I distinguish in `core_config_data` the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to the correct domain if `value` is set incorrectly?

For example:

1. row
   config_id: 2
   scope: default
   scope_id: 0
    path: web/unsecure/base_url
   value: http://www.com/
2. row
   config_id: 3
   scope: default
   scope_id: 0
    path: web/secure/base_url
   value: https://www.com/
3. row
   config_id: 837
   scope: stores
   scope_id: 7
    path: web/unsecure/base_url
   value: http://www.com/
4. row
   config_id: 838
   scope: stores
   scope_id: 7
    path: web/secure/base_url
   value: https://www.com/
5. row
   config_id: 883
   scope: stores
   scope_id: 9
    path: web/unsecure/base_url
   value: http://www.com/
6. row
   config_id: 884
   scope: stores
   scope_id: 9
    path: web/secure/base_url
   value: https://www.com/
7. row
   config_id: 951
   scope: websites
   scope_id: 6
    path: web/unsecure/base_url
   value: http://www.com/
8. row
   config_id: 952
   scope: websites
   scope_id: 6
    path: web/secure/base_url
   value: https://www.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea:

Look in the table '**core_website**' in the database, over here you will find all the "website id's" for your installation as well as what you named each store.

Next match the '**website_id**' to the '**scope_id**' in the **core_config_data** table (where the path is web/unseucre/base_url etc).

Let us know if you need further assistance